# Consecutive Days User Login

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, rank

Below is a table called FactDailyUsers, which contains the users who were active on a specific date with the specific action they have made (aggregate total actions per row).

Write a query that calculates the logic of day_in_row field, no joins are allowed (day_in_row shows consecutive days for user- users that return day after day to the website per row).

FactDailyUsers example

```
user_id date    Action  day_in_row  total_actions
1123    21/06/2018  Pageview    1   1
3321    20/06/2018  Pageview    1   6 
3321    20/06/2018  Click   1   2
2122    19/05/2018  Pageview    1   1
2212    21/06/2018  Pageview    2   1
2212    20/06/2018  Pageview    1   1
2212    24/06/2018  Pageview    1   4
2212    24/06/2018  click   1   2
3321    21/06/2018  pageview    2   4
3321    21/06/2018  click   2   3
3321    17/06/2018  pageview    1   1
```

I just need to find the logic on how to populate the day_in_row column.. the result table should have the user_id the consecutive days and the day_in_row field.

I tried the below query. But i dont get what i should change to get just the number of consecutive days alone.

```
select user_id, count(*) as numdays, min(date) as startTime, max(date) as endTime
from 
(select fd.*,dateadd(day, dense_rank() over (partition by user_id order by date),date) as rn
from factdailyusers fd) fd
group by employee, rn;
```

Comment: tag your rdbms or dw service and provide sample  desired output

Comment: and you have to explain the logic behind "day_in_row" column.

Comment: day_in_row shows consecutive days for user that is the users that return day after day to the website per row

Comment: _Specify_ the expected result too. And show us your current query attempt.

Comment: SO is not a homework completing service, you are expected to show what you have so far and explain where you are having trouble. Please read [No attempt made](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)

Comment: hey @Stu I tried using dense rank but i dont clearly understand the question. I posted here to understand it in a better way.

Comment: hey @Stu please find my query. Its my bad that i did not place it here, doesnt mean you can say out things man! Common!

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem that is generally called "gaps and islands". Here's what I came up with given your data:

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY;
WITH d AS (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES 
        (1123, cast('21/06/2018' as date), 'Pageview', 1, 1),
        (3321, cast('20/06/2018' as date), 'Pageview', 1, 6), 
        (3321, cast('20/06/2018' as date), 'Click',    1, 2),
        (2122, cast('19/05/2018' as date), 'Pageview', 1, 1),
        (2212, cast('21/06/2018' as date), 'Pageview', 2, 1),
        (2212, cast('20/06/2018' as date), 'Pageview', 1, 1),
        (2212, cast('24/06/2018' as date), 'Pageview', 1, 4),
        (2212, cast('24/06/2018' as date), 'click',    1, 2),
        (3321, cast('21/06/2018' as date), 'pageview', 2, 4),
        (3321, cast('21/06/2018' as date), 'click',    2, 3),
        (3321, cast('17/06/2018' as date), 'pageview', 1, 1)
    ) AS x(USER_ID, date,    ACTION,  day_in_row,  total_actions)
), dt_table AS (
    SELECT n.n, DATEADD(DAY, n.n - 1, m.mn) AS d
    FROM (
        SELECT MIN(d.date) AS mn, MAX(d.date) AS mx
        FROM d
    ) AS m
    JOIN dbo.Numbers AS n
        on n.n <= DATEDIFF(DAY, m.mn, m.mx)+1
)
, g AS (
    SELECT *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d.USER_ID, d.ACTION ORDER BY d.date) AS r
    FROM d
), i AS (
    SELECT *, r - n AS island
    FROM g
    JOIN dt_table AS dt
        ON dt.d = g.date
)
SELECT *, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY 
            i.USER_ID, 
            i.ACTION, 
            i.island 
        ORDER BY i.date
    ) AS calculated_day_in_row
FROM i
ORDER BY USER_ID, ACTION, date;
```

It's a lot, but let's break it down.

The first CTE merely presents your data in a way that it can be used in queries. As a note - doing this yourself in the question will increase the likelihood that people will help you because it reduces the friction for them doing so.

The second CTE (dt_table) gets the min/max dates and creates a mini calendar table. dbo.Numbers is just a one column table with the number 1 through something big-ish (I chose 10000 for this demo). The purpose here is to contiguously enumerate all of the possible dates a user could have had interaction.

The third CTE (g) enumerates the data as it is based on the criteria you've outlined (you're trying to identify islands based on the same user performing the same action on successive days).

The fourth CTE (i) is the key realization in the "gaps and islands" approach. Values that are in the same "island" will have the same value for the difference between the previous two enumerations. The actual value that difference attains isn't important.

With all that prep work done, we can finally select what we want. To get the column you want, we enumerate rows that are in the same island.